# Any way to automatically trigger launch of my app

Tags: iphone, triggers, launch

Is there any way to automatically launch my app when the iPhone receives an external phone call?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is there *any* way? Maybe if you jailbreak it and dig around in the private frameworks, which is something I don't know much about. As for an officially documented method, you're very out of luck.

In iOS, to launch an app that is not currently running or suspended, you use a [custom URL scheme](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StandardBehaviors/StandardBehaviors.html). The OS comes standard with built in support for a few different schemes, `tel` being one of them. Supporting this scheme is what makes the Phone app launch automatically with a telephone number. According to the docs:

> The handlers for these schemes are
>   fixed and cannot be changed. If your
>   URL type includes a scheme that is
>   identical to one defined by Apple, the
>   Apple-provided application is launched
>   instead of your application.

So, even if you were to explicitly support the scheme, the OS would trump your app with the phone app.